# How can I get the attributes of a model through a rest call in Sails

Tags: node.js, rest, sails.js

I'd like to get the attributes of a model through an HTTP REST call. I would like to know the attribute names and the datatype. How can I achieve this?

An example is if I want to get the attributes of a `user` model. So I would like to make an HTTP call such as a `GET` to `localhost/users/attributes` which would return:

```
{
    id: integer,
    username: string,
    ...
}
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer. I made a route on the model's controller.js file. I added this:

```
    module.exports = {

            attributes: function (req, res) {
            var message = sails.models.categories.attributes;
            console.log(message);
            res.json(message);

        }
    };
```

Then I navigated to `localhost/<model name>/attributes`.